# What does 'pub run' differs from normal execution?

Tags: dart

I find there are some differences that I can't figure out which nor how when executing a binary with`pub run bin_executable.dart args` rather than `dart bin/bin_executable.dart args`.

Execution is notably slow in the first form, and the output is worst, sometimes erroneous...

I searched [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-run) but didn't find anything useful. Any help?

Comment: Can you provide a specific example from running your code with both dart and pub?

Answer (score 3):

`pub run bin_executable.dart` runs `pub`, and `pub` starts an new process that runs `dart bin_executable.dart`

There was a recent change that allows `pub` to run `bin_executable.dart` in a new Dart isolate instead of a new process. That might make it a little faster but I think the main purpose is to allow to attach a debugger to debug `bin_executable.dart` when run with `pub` (especially for `pub run test`)

I assume the main part or the slower execution is the start time for `pub`