# What's the difference (and preferred cmd) of "pub run" and "dart" command?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I couldn't find in [the docs](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk) what are the differences (and which is preferred) between these 2 commands.

I can use both:

[pub run](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-run)

```sh
pub run myscript.dart
```

or

[dart](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-vm)

```sh
dart myscript.dart
```

What are the differences between them?

I'm aware of this question: [What does 'pub run' differs from normal execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658586/what-does-pub-run-differs-from-normal-execution), but it's old and doesn't answer the question.